# Is badge awarding still not working properly?

Tags: discussion, badges, top-bar

I am told I have earned the Informed badge and to to "See my profile", but the Informed badge is missing from the profile.

[image]

EDIT:

1) Still missing.

2) For comparison, subsequently I was told I earned the Quorum badge, and this does appear on the profile:

[image]

Comment: @chrisjj Did you actually read the About page on SO or did this notification come completely out of nowhere?

Comment: You haven't been awarded it according to the [general history page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) (just adding information).

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks. In contrast, the subsequent Quorum badge does appear on [the general history page](http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/1134/zsfr.png).